# Add helper via plugin

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I created a helper what adds a css class to links which are pointing to the current url. I want to create a plugin with the same functionality.

I am almost done, as if I use the following code in my `/src/View/AppView.php` file than everything is working.

`$this->loadHelper('Html', ['className' => 'MenuLink.MenuLink']);`

What I want is to let the plugin load the helper. I tried to create an `AppView.php` in my plugin's `View` folder but it seems to be ignored.

How to load a helper via a plugin?

Comment: This seems unclear. You want to be able to call your helper from inside the plugin, or you want to move the helper into a plugin and have your main app load it from there?

Comment: @GregSchmidt My plugin is just this helper. What I want is to let the plugin load the helper for all views without using loadhelper in /src/View/AppView.php

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. It would let plugins override what helpers the main app is loading, with often negative repercussions. For example, if you were to make this plugin public and others used it, `$this->Html` in their views would always refer to your helper, when they might only want that in some views.

Comment: You can, of course, load your helper in your AppController instead of AppView, using the `$helpers` initialization.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Ah I see, I want something what is impossible by design. :) Ok than I just do it in `/src/View/AppView.php`. Thanks for clarifing.